# Raster to points with the missing values

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm using the function `rasterToPoints()` from the package `raster`. By default, this function omits the `NA` values.

```r
raster <- raster(matrix(c(1,2,NA, 1,2,3, 1,2,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3 ))
raster_points <- rasterToPoints(raster, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Therefore, I put a raster with 200 cells and I get a data.frame with only 150 rows. How can I obtain the point with empty cells in my final data.frame?

Answer (score 5):

You could combine `xyFromCell`, `values`, and `cbind`.  This returns the central coordinates of each cell (when you initialized the raster, it assumes a 1 x 1 extent unless defined otherwise) and its value, including `NAs`, in matrix form:

```
cbind(xyFromCell(raster, 1:ncell(raster)), values(raster))
```